# How to display a button or label when right clicking on a ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM, I've build few things, and now tryining to display a delete "button" when user right clicks on a ListBox item.
My listbox looks like this righ now

```
 <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="QUERYNAME" 
                 SelectedValuePath="USERQUERYID" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RS.SavedQueryList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding RS.SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Margin="521,74,0,0" TabIndex="0">
```

Thanks

Comment: a button do you mean a contextmenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="QUERYNAME" 
                 SelectedValuePath="USERQUERYID" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RS.SavedQueryList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding RS.SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Margin="521,74,0,0" TabIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="pack://application:,,,/Img/Delete.png" />
                 </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>      
</ListBox>
```

Obviously you'll need to use some Command with your MenuItem...

Comment: I've added your code, but how would I pass the value of the item which right click was clicke - if using ICommand? I've added this in public ICommand RemovefromListBoxcmd { get { return new DelegateCommand(Remove, CanProceed); } } and this <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding RemovefromListBoxcmd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

Comment: No need to pass it in, in your VM bind SelectedItem property of your ListBox and when the command is executed in your VM just grab it from there...

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that.

Comment: You could also name your ListBox and use CommandParameter property witht that named ListBox SelectedItem property... e.g. MyListBox.SelectedItem

Answer (score 1):

You can add the button and label (in fact, any element you want) to a `ContextMenu` and assign that `ContextMenu` to `ListBoxItem`s. For example, in my `Window`, I'll have something like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Delete This Item" Margin="10"/>
                        <Button Content="Delete"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This will use the power of `Styles` to apply a customized `ContextMenu` to all `ListBoxItem`s the window. After that you can bind `Button.Command` to your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using the MVVM light behavior **EventToCommand** see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Set the event to **MouseRightButtonUp**